# A great YAML library for ruby?

Tags: ruby

Could anyone suggest a well-documented and well known YAML library for ruby?

A book I read used one like this:

```
YAML.load_file(conf.rc).each do |k,v|
  conf.send("#{k}=", v)
end
```

Anyone know which library is used?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's party of the standard library. Just put

```
require 'yaml'
```

in your file and you can use it. Read more [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html).